# In excel, extract a string of numbers within the middle of a string

Tags: excel-formula

I have a column of data with a time stamp. I need to only extract the following:  "14:04:43" from strings that contain "Thu Oct 06 14:04:43 2016 (GMT-04:00)".

This is just the first cell, there are many more with different time stamps. I want to place this in a different column.

Here's my attempt, but failing.

=MID(LEFT(D28,FIND(CHAR(11),D2)-1),FIND(CHAR(20),D2)+1,LEN(D2))

I've tried to do this in excel vba, but think if it can be done with a simple code then I would rather have it that way.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just mid(D2, 11, 8)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=--MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)-2,8)
```

Then format it as time.

Answer (score 0):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),4*999-998,999))
```

[image]

This assumes that your data is a set of sub-strings, separated by spaces, and that we want the 4<sup>th</sup> sub-string.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub checktime()
    Dim element As Range
    For Each element In Range("D1:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row)
        element.Offset(0, 1).Value = Mid(Left(element.Value, InStr(element.Value, "(") - 2), InStr(element.Value, " ") + 1, Len(element.Value))
    Next element
End Sub
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).